# sender() results in deadLetters for implementation but not in unit tests

Tags: scala, akka

I'm working with Akka classic actors (running in Play framework) and am running into a problem with the `sender()` method. When I build and run the code (using `sbt run`), I can see that `sender()` resolves to `deadLetters` actor. However, when running unit tests for that actor, `sender()` resolves to the correct ActorRef (even though it shouldn't).

The `sender()` is being invoked from within a closing future which is why I'm seeing the `deadLetters` when running the actual implementation. However, for some reason, I'm not seeing the `deadLetters` in the unit tests. Any ideas to why there is a difference of behavior between the unittests and running instance?

**Some sample code to give an idea of the code structure**

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  private def throwError() = {
    // THIS IS WHERE sender() BEHAVIOR DIFFERENTIATES BETWEEN IMPLEMENTATION AND UNITTESTS
    sender() ! MyErrorMessage()

    throw new Exception()
  }

  private def myFutureMethod(args: SomeType): Future[Done] = {
    for {
       Some logic here...
    } yield {
      if (some logic check...)
        throwError()
      else
        Done
    }
  }

  override def stepReceive = {
    case MyMessage(args) => 
      myFutureMethod(args)
  }
}
```

**Some sample code to give an idea of the unittest structure**

```
  "My failure test case" in {
    val testProbe = TestProbe()

    myActorImpl.tell(MyMessage(args), testProbe)

    // testProbe SHOULD BE NOT BE RECEIVING A MESSAGE BASED ON THE ABOVE
    // IMPLEMENTATION, BUT IT DOES.
    testProbe.expectNoMessage()
  }
```

If anyone has some tips or ideas for debugging, that would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `sender` in code executed as part of a `Future` within an actor is non-deterministic (viz. a race condition) because your `MyActor` can move on to processing another message before the code in the `Future` executes, and if it has since then, `sender` will have changed, potentially to `deadLetters`.

In your test, if `myActorImpl` hasn't processed a message, `sender` will still point to the test probe.

Assuming you want the message to actually be sent to the sender, you need to capture it before handing it to the `Future`, along these lines

```scala
class MyActor extends Actor {
  private def throwError(target: ActorRef) = {
    // uses the captured sender, no race condition
    target ! MyErrorMessage()

    throw new Exception()
  }

  private def myFutureMethod(args: SomeType, sender: ActorRef): Future[Done] = {
    for {
       Some logic here...
    } yield {
      if (some logic check...)
        throwError(sender)
      else
        Done
    }
  }

  override def stepReceive = {
    case MyMessage(args) => 
      myFutureMethod(args, sender)  // captures the sender reference
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your answer, it clarifies a lot.